# how do I remove an image and then read, with different characteristics in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want to add an image after pressing a button, then remove it after pressing the button again and add the same image with a different size and location. I tried using

> imageView.image = nil

but that did not work, as nothing at all would show!

```
@IBAction func btnCalc(sender: AnyObject) {
    let Lead1 = txtLead1.text
    let LeadI: Float = (Lead1! as NSString).floatValue
    let Lead2 = txtLead2.text
    let LeadII: Float = (Lead2! as NSString).floatValue
    let Lead3 = txtLead3.text
    let LeadIII: Float = (Lead3! as NSString).floatValue
    let a = 0.5*(LeadII + LeadIII)
    let b = 0.5*(LeadI - LeadIII)
    let c = (-0.5*(LeadI + LeadII))
    let d :Float = 2/1.7320508075688772935274463415058723669428052538103806280558
    let e = LeadIII/LeadI
    let y :Float = Float (atan(d*(e+0.5)))
    let z = (y*180)/3.141592654
    let z1 = z + 180
    let zz = LeadI/(cos((z*3.141592654)/180))
    let zzz = -zz
    let Z1 = CGFloat((z1*3.141592654)/180)
    let Z = CGFloat((z*3.141592654)/180)
    let imageName = "Arrow.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

    if LeadI == 0 && LeadII == 0 && LeadIII == 0 {
        lblaVF.text = "aVF = 0"
        lblaVL.text = "aVL = 0"
        lblaVR.text = "aVR = 0"
        lblmEA.text = "Mean Electrical Axis = 0"
        lblA.text = "A = 0"

        //Remove old image from view

    } else if LeadII == LeadIII + LeadI && zz<0 {
        lblaVF.text = "aVF = \(a)"
        lblaVL.text = "aVL = \(b)"
        lblaVR.text = "aVR = \(c)"
        lblmEA.text = "Mean Electrical Axis = \(z1)"
        lblA.text = "A = \(zzz)"


        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 107, y: 340, width: 160, height: 24)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(Z1)
    } else if LeadII == LeadIII + LeadI {
        lblaVF.text = "aVF = \(a)"
        lblaVL.text = "aVL = \(b)"
        lblaVR.text = "aVR = \(c)"
        lblmEA.text = "Mean Electrical Axis = \(z)"
        lblA.text = "A = \(zz)"

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 107, y: 340, width: 160, height: 24)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(Z)

    } else {

        //Remove old image from view

        lblaVF.text = "aVF ="
        lblaVL.text = "aVL ="
        lblaVR.text = "aVR ="
        lblmEA.text = "Mean Electrical Axis ="
        lblA.text = "A ="
        let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Houston, we've got a problem!", message:"Rememer that Lead II = Lead I + Lead III", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK",style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your example all of this is happening in an `IBAction` and each time you're creating a new `UIImageView`. So if your are setting the `image` to nil of a newly created `UIImageView` you will see no effect since it has not yet been added to a view.

It looks like you will need an instance variable on your view controller for the `UIImageView`. Add the imageView once in `viewDidLoad` and then modify it in the IBAction rather than create a new one each time.

There are other things to consider here which could help your debugging:

- Perhaps you should consider breaking this up into smaller methods so with instance variables on the view controller to hold some state.
- Variable names should be meaningful rather than (a,b,c,d etc.)
- Variable names should begin with lowercase and classes with uppercase for clarity.
- Avoid magic numbers as much as possible particularly when there are available alternatives eg. M_PI instead of 3.14....

Comment: This is great advice, thank you! But I tried to do this, still not sure.

Comment: How can I actually declare it in viewdidload then use it elsewhere?